# Подскажите книги по JavaScript

Tags: javascript, книги

ознакомился с основами js в книге js для детей. Ищу книгу с алгоритмизацией, например "Грокаем алгоритмы" только на js

Comment: Алгоритмы от ЯП не зависят

Comment: так алгоритмы везде одинаковые, если прочтите Грокаем с начала до конца, то явно себе что то полезное найдёте, а вот сухая теория без практики плохо, так еще лучше разбить по темах и решать задачки после теории.

Comment: Я в шоке. При таком огромном количестве интерактивных обучалок JavaScript кто-то до сих пор ищет бумажные книги.